# Get child of list ui li dropdown knockout.js data binding

Tags: knockout.js

Help pls. I have 22 objects, 5 parents and 17 for childs.
I can't get the child of the ui li. using data binding
knock out js. the 5 parent only displayed. thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P10rF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEc6A.png)

Index.js

```
self._routes = ko.observableArray([]);
    self._child = ko.observableArray([]);
    for (var i = 0; i < backend.user().UserScreens.length; i++) {
        var str = backend.user().UserScreens[i].addOn; //add icon
        str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1); //trim last character ','
        if (backend.user().UserScreens[i].isParent || backend.user().UserScreens[i] == null) {
            self._routes.push({
                route: backend.user().UserScreens[i].linkURL,
                title: backend.user().UserScreens[i].description,
                moduleId: 'modules/' + backend.user().UserScreens[i].linkURL.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '').replace(/\s{2,10}/g, ' ') + '/index',
                nav: true,
                _icon: 'fa ' + str,
                _id: '#' + backend.user().UserScreens[i].id
            });
        }
        else {
            self._child.push({
                childRoute: backend.user().UserScreens[i].linkURL,
                childtitle: backend.user().UserScreens[i].description,
                childmoduleId: 'modules/' + backend.user().UserScreens[i].linkURL.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '').replace(/\s{2,10}/g, ' ') + '/index',
                childNav: true,
                childIcon: 'fa ' + str,
                childId: '#' + backend.user().UserScreens[i].id
            });
        }
    }
```

Index.html

```
<ul class="nav">
                <li data-bind="foreach: _routes"> 
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: _id }"><span data-bind="attr: {class: _icon}"></span>
                        <span class="sidebar-title" data-bind="text: title"></span><span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: _child, attr: {id: childId}" class="nav sub-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" data-bind="attr: {href: '#' + childRoute}">
                            <span data-bind="attr: {class: _icon}"></span>
                            <span data-bind="text: childtitle"></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model shows `_routes` and `_child` at same level thats why.

```
self._routes = ko.observableArray([]);
self._child = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Therefore your foreach on `child` will fall over as the `child` property doesn't exist. The fix would be to remove `child` from the route foreach or add `$parent`

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li data-bind="foreach: _routes"> 
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: _id }"><span data-bind="attr: {class: _icon}"></span>
            <span class="sidebar-title" data-bind="text: title"></span><span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent._child -->
        <ul data-bind="attr: {id: childId}" class="nav sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#" data-bind="attr: {href: '#' + childRoute}">
                <span data-bind="attr: {class: _icon}"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: childtitle"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

But this will display all children foreach route, but i dont see any correlation between route and child so this may be what your looking.

Comment: Thanks sir. Newbie in knockout.js. :)